# Does the hudson msbuild plugin parse a given log file other that the console output

Tags: hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I know that Hudson msbuild plugin parses the console output. Is it possible to direct Hudson to parse a given log file at some path other than the console output?

Comment: @Slav. I am trying to parse the build log for build errors.

Comment: Neither Hudson, nor any build plugin (i.e. msbuild plugin) "parse" the console output. Hudson simply displays ("tails", to be precise) the console output of the command line session. If the command displays console output, it will be captured and displayed; if the command runs silent, Hudson won't have anything to display besides it's own actions. It is not clear what you want: Do you want to display the output of some file? At runtime or after completion? Or do you want to **parse** the file, i.e. ***automatically** process it for certain patterns*?

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some clarification from comments: the OP wants to use [**Log Parse Plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) to parse a file other than the console output.

It doesn't look like that plugin allows to select a source of the log, other than console. However you can display your other log file into the console output, and then the plugin will pick it up.

Add the following to your "Execute Windows Batch command" step, probably after the build:
`type path/to/filename`
Provide a path to the filename you want to display, either relative to `%WORKSPACE%` or absolute.